# Jquery form submit() call back not working

Tags: jquery

I have an iframe and a form. Form's target is iframe. When I submit form, the result page should load in iframe. I have attached the code below:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function submitForm() {
 $("form#testForm").submit(function(){
   alert('hii')
  });
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<iframe name="testFrame" id="testFrame" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" width="500"     height="200"></iframe>
<form name="testForm" id="testForm" action="http://www.yahoo.com" target="testFrame">    </form>

<button name="testBtn" value="submit" onclick="submitForm();">submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The alert is not coming....Help me please...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the [docs say](http://api.jquery.com/submit/), if you call a jQuery event method with an argument, it adds an event handler rather than firing the event. You need to add the event handler outside `submitForm`.

```
$(document).ready($("form#testForm").submit(function(){
   alert('hii')
});


function submitForm() {
    $("form#testForm").submit();
}
```

Comment: one more thing...how can i get the content height of the loaded page ? $("#iframeName").contents().find("body").height() is not working...any idea ? it gives 0...:(

Comment: @Aneesh: SO is a Q&A site, not a forum. New questions should be asked as new questions, not in comments. The reason your code doesn't work, in brief (since that's all that comments allow for), is that the iframe contents are in a different domain, so you can't.